# ¿Qué significa "nariz de bola"?

Tags: modismos, saludos

Hoy en chat, una amiga me saludó con:

> Hola hola nariz de bola!

La pregunté que quería decir, y solo me dijo que es un saludo agredable.  Pero todavía quiero saber que significa.  ¿Es una frase común? ¿Dónde?

Comment: Primera vez que lo veo. Vallisoletano de toda la vida.

Comment: Nunca lo había visto antes. Se parece al Hola caracola que comenta SysDragon que sí he oído y utilizado a menudo. Simplemente parece un modo de hacer un saludo más musical añadiéndole la rima, no creo que tenga ningún significado especial.

Answer (score 3):

Es una rima.

> ¡*Hola* nariz de *bola*!

Por cierto, esto es una nariz de bola, usada por los payasos:

[image]

Lo mismo da decir eso,

> Hola caracola

u

> ¡Hola cara de bola!

Lo único que quería hacer ella es rimar el saludo.  Lo único que puedes deducir es que tu amiga está de buen humor, pero no tiene significado más allá de eso.

Answer (score 1):

Es una expresión común en Mexico, en donde se le suele decir a los niños. Es un saludo cariñoso e informal.

En España, un buen símil sería:

> ¡Hola caracola!

Answer (score 1):

"¡Hola hola nariz de bola!" no tiene significado en si mismo más allá del que tiene "Hola". Se utiliza para saludos cariñosos, especialmente a niños, debido a que rima, al igual que "Hola caracola".

Answer (score 1):

Son palabras tontas que riman con lo que se dice, pero no significan, nada ademas de eso,
son para usarse con alguien de confianza o que conozcamos bien.
Aca les dejo algunas, que encontrado.

> obvio microbio
>
> neta camioneta
>
> chao pescao
>
> k onda microonda
>
> tache guarache
>
> que pez mi acuaman
>
> empates - cuates
>
> corazón - calzón
>
> borracho - gacho
>
> noche - coche
>
> piña - niña
>
> luna - tuna
>
> neta-patineta
>
> hola nariz de bola

Comment: No entiendo pq el voto negativo?...Que bola!!!

Comment: Gracias amigo Emilio tampoco entendi porque el 'vote down', solo hice una coleccion. Pero bueno parece que al final han entendido que no estaba mal.Saludos a todos. Parece que eres cubano?? Por el que bola!!! es algo que se usa en Cuba.

Comment: si soy cubano asere...lol...slang from our country, es bueno encontrarse con paisanos por estos lares...saludos

Comment: si es realmente bueno, veo que al igual que yo te gusta la programacion, por la presencia en stackoverflow, yo tambien la visito hace un tiempo, si algun dias necesitas alguna colaboracion en algun trabajo or whatever, puedes contar conmigo sin problems. Saludos.